# Reading part of a line to store in a variable

Tags: c++, variables, fstream, readline

I'm trying to get the rest of a string from a file to store the string in a variable. For example, the first line is "1234 Shanghai, China" but the variable query only gets "Shanghai," instead of "Shanghai, China." Weight gets 1234. I'm guessing it has something to do with the space between the city and country.

```
while (!file.eof())
{
    string query;
    long weight;
    file >> weight >> query;
    Term inputTerm(query,weight);
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using the standard iostream classes?

Comment: If you are you could use file.getLine()

Comment: I am now using getline(file, line). Still facing the same problem.

Comment: Post the code then please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
long weight;
char query[100];
while (file >> weight)
{
    file.getline(query, 100);
    Term inputTerm(std::string(query), weight);
}
```

Comment: Yours worked! Where can I find information on the meaning of "char query[100]"?

Comment: Any book covering the basics. it's simply a array of 100 char's to be used as a buffer to read the line into. the 100 passed to the getline function is the max amount of characters to read and matches the buffer size so it never overflows the buffer.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I guess the book I read wasn't a very good one then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to read the rest of a line:

```
std::string ReadLine(std::ifstream& file){
    char buf[1024]; //Unfortunately this means you can only have a max of 1024 char string
    file.getline(&(buf[0]),1024,'\n');
    return std::string(buf);
}
```

Use like this:

```
file >> weight;
query = ReadLine(file);
```